# How do we do "String + selected value in a combobox" using System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to have a program that would copy and paste files on different directories. Part of the program needs to identify a directory path and a sub directory path. I can't seem to get the sub directory path.

I have tried using System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories to get this done but I only have been able to get the 1st directory path. My code doesnt seem to provide the correct output for the 2nd combobox directing to the sub folders

```
    Dim x As String
    x = "k:\example"
    For Each Dir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(x)
        Dim dirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Dir)
        SaveComboBox1.Items.Add(dirInfo.Name)
    Next
    Dim z As String
    z = "k:\example\" & SaveComboBox1.Text & "\"
    For Each Dir2 As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(z)
        Dim dirInfo2 As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Dir2)
        SaveComboBox2.Items.Add(dirInfo2.Name)
    Next
```

What I was wanting is for the 2nd combobox to show the subfolders when the user selects a folder on the 1st combobox

*1st combo box contains a,b,c folders for example
then in the 2nd combobox, their subfolders would be enlisted whenever the user selects 1 folder in the 1st combobox
But this doesnt seem to happen with my code

"k:\example\" & SaveComboBox1.Text & "\" -- doesnt seem to work or I might be missing something else

Comment: `SaveComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name" SaveComboBox1.ValueMember = "FullName" SaveComboBox1.DataSource = new DirectoryInfo(YourStartingPath).GetDirectories()`. In `SaveComboBox1.`[`SelectionChangeCommitted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted) event handler, add: `SaveComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Name" SaveComboBox2.ValueMember = "FullName" SaveComboBox2.DataSource = new DirectoryInfo(SaveComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()).GetDirectories()`.

Comment: Oh wow, this works like wonder...Had to  study this format.Thank you so much Jimi. Your a life saver